# Getting the byte length of the text inside a PangoLayout

Tags: pango

I'm trying to find a way to figure out the byte length of the text inside the  `PangoLayout`. I'm setting the text like this:

```
pango_layout_set_markup(layout, "<i>Hello World</i>", -1);
```

Since the markup tags don't count as part of the text, the byte length of this layout is 11 but I don't seem to be able to get this value from Pango. It only allows me to get the number of characters using `pango_layout_get_character_count()` but this returns the number of characters, not the bytes.

The reason why I need the byte length of the text inside the layout is that I want to find out the cursor position after the last character, so I need to pass the byte length of the text inside the `PangoLayout` to `pango_layout_get_cursor_pos()` to get that cursor position.

However, I don't seem to find a way to get this byte length. Of course, I could calculate it manually but before doing that I'd first like to ask if there's a Pango way to get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, of course the solution is rather obvious. Just get the text from the layout and use `strlen` to compute its byte length, i.e.

```
size_t bytelen = strlen(pango_layout_get_text(f->layout));
```